# Who needs to fill out RAP as a Service for SharePoint questionnaire?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

We as a vendor have installed SharePoint in an organization. Client has asked us to fill out a questionnaire called "RAP as a Service Provider for SharePoint Server".

Basically client logged into his Microsoft online account and opened the questionnaire and asked us to fill out. Does this questionnaire needs to be filled out by vendor or client? I am confused.

Comment: It depends on what your agreement say. If it's not mentioned there, you don't have to. What does your agreement say?

Comment: I don't have agreement but looks like this needs to be filled by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The questionaire is for the administrator of the site, the IT infrastructure people of the data center which is normally the client. If you are the vendor who is responsible of the solution (outsourcing services) the rap tool is for you so you can do the questionaire on behalf of the client (with your email address filled in at the end, just before you submit the results).